# How do i link database relationship with the following information?

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys, relationship

I have been relentlessly trying to edit my database relationships but to no avail. Here is the scenario:

i have an inventory table. an inventory can be classified into 2 categories(technical eg. guns, radios and general eg. uniforms). i was hoping there could be a way for me to add details(from different tables eg. technical_inventory_table and general_inventory_table) to the inventory table through the category since the two categories have different fields. is there any way for me to do that? please do note that a technical inventory will be listed individually since a single item will have a serial number attached to it.

or does the answer provided here - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33099/storing-different-products-and-joining-on-table-names - be an already good solution for my problem? i would like to avoid creating a table where it will be made up of what usually are the fieldnames as described in the link to prevent confusion within my team.

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: The solution in that question is more general, because you don't have to hard-code column names for every type of detail. As you expand to new types of products, with different attributes, you don't have to change your schema at all.

Comment: @Barmar but as i see it, if i simply created a table without hard-coding the column names for the details it would leave too much null values in my database.